# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on an acer aspire 3690 (Win Vista)?

Tags: boot, acer, windows-vista

newbie here. I am trying to learn how to use ubuntu, so I would like to run it in an old computer. I have followed the steps, but I can´t seem to get it to boot from a dvd nor usb port with the iso file I downloaded. I´ve already tried to move the bios with no results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you try to boot?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps to create your installation media :
1.Download the .iso file from Ubuntu website.
2.Download a software named Universal USB installer.
3.Run it to create a bootable USB drive.
4.Use the bootable USB drive to test drive Ubuntu or install it. 
If you want suggestion on how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows , please feel free to ask.
Hope this helps